# Performance related for conversion from String array to ArrayList

Tags: java

I am converting an empty String array (which i may get from middleware)  to List .

For Conversion process i used Arrays.asList (Please see below code ) which is throwing an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException .

```
public class Ramddd {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] words = null;
        if (words == null) {
            words = new String[0];
        }
        List<String> newWatchlist = Arrays.asList(words);
        List<String> other = new ArrayList<String>();
        other.add("ddd");
        newWatchlist.addAll(other);
    }

}



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at Ramddd.main(Ramddd.java:18)
```

**I dont get this Error if i use**

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            mylist.add(words[i]);
        }
```

This forms an proper `List`  and any operations like `addALL` , `removeALL` seems good , but dont want to go to this for loop approach , as it may result in performance .
Please let me know what is the best and safe approach for converting a String array to ArrayList .

Comment: That will make it a little better: List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>(words.length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
public class Ramddd {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] words = getWords();
        if (words == null) {
            words = new String[0];
        }
        List<String> other = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
        other.add("ddd");
    }
}
```

In terms of performance, I don't this this is something to worry about, unless you have a really gigantic array of Strings.

Comment: the response is dynamic one , i cant know earlier if its null or contains anything .

Comment: sometimes the array a Gigantic one ( 150 words) ( so dont want to affect the application performance .)

Comment: I would say a Gigantic array would be in the millions of records.  A size of 150 is very small.  Anyways, you should always rely on empirical evidence when optimizing performance.  Don't prematurely optimize!

Answer (score 1):

The method [`java.util.Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. This implementation of `List` for this method (`java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`) don't have support for these methods. See the documentation for the [`java.util.AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

If you know the total size of your list of words, you can init the capacitity for [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), adding n elements requires *O*(*n*) time. If you don't know the final size, use LinkedList.

See more in [List Implementations (The Java Tutorials > Collections > Implementations)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html).